# How is socket.io secured natively?

Tags: security, socket.io

I'm looking at socket.io packets and they are TCP. When I review the value, I see encrypted data. Where and how is socket.io encrypting the messages that pass through the soccket? Is it really secure? This is a VM running with requests over http.

For example, I see

`0000   bc ec 23 c3 64 6a 00 15 5d 01 59 06 08 00 45 08   ..#.dj..].Y...E.`

`0010   00 58 68 cc 40 00 40 06 4e 6c c0 a8 01 05 c0 a8   .Xh.@.@.Nl......`

`0020   01 0a 00 16 c6 51 15 15 7f 44 69 87 60 58 50 18   .....Q...Di.\`XP.`

`0030   0b 2e 6c ae 00 00 8b 6f 92 7f b9 1b c2 d6 54 60   ..l....o......T`

`0040   5e 24 65 2a 0c d6 87 90 fd 87 63 30 9d 69 11 26   ^$e*......c0.i.&`

`0050   4d 75 8c 7b 5e b2 ad 47 12 9d 05 d0 7c 3b 7c 9e   Mu.{^..G....|;|.`

`0060   b1 0d a0 b7 f1 88                                 ......`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about whether or not something is "secure" without a detailed threat model. What is your precise definition of "secure"? What are you securing? Who are you securing it against? How much is whatever you are securing worth to you? How much is it worth to your attacker? How much are you willing to spend to secure it? How much is your attacker willing to spend to break it? What are the attack vectors?

Comment: I would also be interested in how you were able to determine that "you see encrypted data" as you wrote in the question. The output of a good encryption algorithm should be indistinguishable from random noise, so the fact that you *were* able to "see encrypted data" seems to indicate that it is *not* secure, because if it were secure, then you wouldn't be able to tell that it is encrypted data. Did you use some form of statistical analysis to come to this conclusion?